# Tables create using Flask-SQLAlchemy, but they are not shown on sqlite command line (shell)

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I am developing a flask application using Flask-SQLAlchemy with the following structure files. When I create the database (db.sqlite3) and write on the sqlite command line `sqlite> .tables` , the table (columns name) creates into the db.py file is not shown in the *shell*. There isn't any messagge error. It's only the *shell* doesn't show anything when I write this command. I have been tried different options I don't know what to do anymore. **How can I get the shell show the columns of the tables?**

**File Tree:**

```
|-PROBATINAS_2 (proyect name)
  |-probatina
    |- __init__.py
    |- db.py
    |- db.sqlite3 (database)
  |-venv
   |- Include
   |- Lib
   |- Scripts
  |-.env
  |-app.py
  |-config.py
```

The code written for these files is as follows:

****init**.py:**

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__, instance_relative_config=True)
app.config.from_object('config')
```

**db.py:**

```
from probatina import app
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI']
SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS = app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS']
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
db.create_all()
#db.init_app(app)

class Customer(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True) 
    first_name = db.Column(db.String(50), nullable=False)
    last_name = db.Column(db.String(50), nullable=False)
    address = db.Column(db.String(500), nullable=False)
    city = db.Column(db.String(50), nullable=False)
    postcode = db.Column(db.String(50), nullable=False)
    email = db.Column(db.String(50), nullable=False, unique=True)

    orders = db.relationship('Order', backref='customer')

order_product = db.Table('order_product',
    db.Column('order_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('order.id'), primary_key=True),
    db.Column('product_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('product.id'), primary_key=True)
)

class Order(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    order_date = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False, default=datetime.utcnow)
    shipped_date = db.Column(db.DateTime)
    delivered_date = db.Column(db.DateTime)
    coupon_code = db.Column(db.String(50))
    customer_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('customer.id'), nullable=False)

    products = db.relationship('Product', secondary=order_product)

class Product(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(50), nullable=False, unique=True)
    price = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)
```

**.env:**

```
FLASK_APP=app.py
FLASK_ENV=development
```

**app.py:**

```
from probatina import app

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app()
```

**config.py:**

```
SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = 'sqlite:///C:/Users/ferna/Documents/Curso Aprender a programar desde cero/probatinas_2/probatina/db.sqlite3'
SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS = False
```

Comment: You have to use `db.commit()`.

Comment: @Klaus D. I'm not sure because I had this proyect in 2 files (app.py and db.sqlite3), previously and it worked perefectly without db.commit() command.  I think the problem is related to the current structure files and someting wrong with the links between the files (some call others), but I'm not sure. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Do you even import `db.py` somewhere?

Comment: `db.create_all()` should be _after_ the model declarations.